# How I do aysnchronously display the results of an SQL query (with ajax)?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I've looked really hard through this site and found similar questions but didn't understand the answers. Perhaps I need to become more familiar with AJAX but here's my problem:

I have a PHP page (mymdb.php) where a user submits info (a first and last name). I have a page that gets the results of a mysql_query (_results.php). Finally, I have a JS page (bacon.js), which is meant to display the results of the query aynschronously (by fading out one div, and sliding down the results above it).

So I'm thinking I need to somehow access the $results of the SQL query, then display them using jquery.html(results). How do I access the php variable $results from the JS page?

There's not a lot of code. Here's the relevant code from the mymdb.php page where the user submits the info:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="bacon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <form method="post" action="mymdb.php" id="search_form">
            <fieldset id="search_box">
                Actor's first last name:
                <input name="first_name" type="text" size="12" id="fname" /> 
                <input name="last_name" type="text" size="12" id="lname" /> 
                <button type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton">go</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <div id="everythingElse">
            <h1>The One Degree of Kevin Bacon</h1>
            <p>
                Type in an actor's name to see if he/she was ever in a movie with Kevin Bacon!
            </p>

            <p id="result_paragraph">

            </p>

            <div id="kevinBaconImg"><img src="http://www.images22.com/pics/04/kevin-bacon-blue-eyes.jpg" alt="Kevin Bacon"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here's the _results.php page where the SQL query is made:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
    mysql_select_db("imdb_small");

    //get all movies the actor is in
    $results1 = mysql_query("SELECT name, year 
        FROM movies m 
            JOIN roles r ON m.id = r.movie_id 
        JOIN actors a ON a.id = r.actor_id 
        WHERE a.first_name = $('#fname').val() AND a.last_name = $('#lname').val();"
    );
?>
```

And here's the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post('mymdb.php', $('#search_form').serialize(), function() {

            $('#result_paragraph').html('<?= $results1 ?>').slideDown(); //this should dislay the results from the query
            $('#kevinBaconImg').fadeOut(); //this image fades out once the user submits the first and last names of the actor

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Lots of code - No Question ....

Comment: @Ed Heal, there is a question just before the code

Comment: You just put a `mysql_query` but not echoing/printing it how would you get the resutls from db.

Comment: @AlexSilverman - Where is the question? _ This is a statement "I've looked really hard through this site and found similar questions but didn't understand the answers. "

Comment: numerous tutorials for php/jquery ajax on web. Start by going through a few so you understand basics of how ajax works

Comment: @EdHeal- Seriously? Well, there's the title: "How do I asynchronously display the results of an SQL query (with ajax). Then there's this sentence in the explanation: "How do I access the php variable $results from the JS page?"

Answer (score 0):

Use the data you get in callback function

I don't know much about php, but it seems you should `echo` result from your php

```
$.post('mymdb.php', $('#search_form').serialize(), function(result) {

            $('#result_paragraph').html(result).slideDown(); //this should dislay the results from the query
            $('#kevinBaconImg').fadeOut(); //this image fades out once the user submits the first and last names of the actor

   });
```

Comment: That ended up moving down the entire contents of the page (including header, form, and image), but did not display any results much less the ones from the query. How is the "result" parameter in your code linked to the $results1 variable from the SQL query?

Comment: result is the variable which get's the data returned by `mymdb.php` , you should echo your result in your php

Comment: Where would I echo it? And is this in addition to or instead of the JS code that changes the innerhtml of the result_paragraph?

Comment: The data you echo with php will be received by JS in the result variable and will be filled in `#result_paragraph`

Comment: That didn't happen. The whole webpage seemed to slideDown() and no query results appeared.